# Amazon Ec2 nfs permission problem

Tags: amazon-ec2, nfs

After sharing the file from nfs server the ownership and group looks like nobody nobody. so how do i change the same permission as what i have in nfs server?
Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the ownership/permissions on the NFS server ?

Comment: The permission and ownership mentioned in the exports file as (rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash), The Particular directory contains the permission like drwx------ 8 john john (inside this directory i need to share some other directories)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of NFS are you using?

You need to make sure you have the idmapd configuration setup.

Comment: The nfs version is 3.2.19 and the idmapd configuration file has been set up like: Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nobody